# Why does numpy indexing with a colon vs. range result in weird behavior?

Tags: python, numpy

Could someone explain the following behavior?

```
test = np.random.rand(1000, 10)
test.shape
(1000, 10)

idxs = np.random.randint(0, 10, 1000)
idxs.shape
(1000,)

test[:, idxs].shape
(1000, 1000)

test[range(test.shape[0]), idxs].shape
(1000,)
```

I would expect these to be equivalent. What am I missing?

Comment: The last returns `test[0, idxs[0]]`, etc. I like to contrast indexing a block with its diagonal.  `numpy` indexing is well documented, but it takes time to read..  It also helps to understand `broadcasting`.

Comment: To get the block: `test[np.arange(test.shape[0])[:,None], idxs]`, that is index with a (1000,1) and (1000,) pair, which broadcasted together give a (1000,1000) block.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has said it explicitly yet: You are missing the [Advanced Indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) section of the reference manual.

> Advanced indexing is triggered when the selection object, obj, is a non-tuple sequence object, an ndarray (of data type integer or bool), or **a tuple with at least one sequence object** or ndarray (of data type integer or bool). There are two types of advanced indexing: integer and Boolean.

(my boldface)

Answer (score 0):

You should print out the two arrays and see.

Using the colon groups by 10, whereas with `range` it doesn't.

You would have to make each value a sublist, let's say the value is `1`, you would have to make it `[1]` to keep the shape and have the same result.

So use the below instead:

```
test[[[i] for i in range(test.shape[0])], idxs].shape
```

Now the full output would be:

```
(1000, 10)
(1000,)
(1000, 1000)
(1000, 1000)
```